# How to convert columns (pandas dataframe) into row for SQL insertion?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, dataset

I have a table **QUESTIONNAIRE** as below:
[image]

The coloumns (EXT1, EXT2, ... are the question's code; the value is the answer for the question)

I have 10000 QuestionnaireID and 50 Question's codes.

I would like to add this into a new table called **ANSWER**:
[image]

Hence, I'll have 50000 row of data.
I can also download the data into pandas dataframe.
How can I do transform it with sql-query or pandas?

Thanks before.
Cheers.

Comment: Checkout the function pd.melt()

Answer (score 0):

I created a simplified version of your dataset, but the solution fits also the complete version:

```
tbl1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "QID": [1,2,3,4],
    "Ext1": [5,6,7,8],
    "Ext2": [9,10,11,12],
    "Ext3": [13,14,15,16]
})
```

Then, I declared a DataFrame with the destination format you want:

```
#Declare table 2 with desired shape 
tbl2 = pd.DataFrame({  
    "QID":[],  
    "QCode":[],  
    "Answer":[]  
})
```

Finally, simply looped through the data and reshaped it 'manually':

```
for idxRow in np.arange((tbl1.shape)[0]):
    for idxCol in np.arange((tbl1.shape)[1]):
        if(idxCol > 0):
            #Get data from tbl1 and prepare in columns
            col1 = tbl1.iloc[idxRow,0] #QID (1st column)
            col2 = (tbl1.columns)[idxCol] # Column name (2nd column)
            col3 = tbl1.iloc[idxRow,idxCol] # Data val (3rd column)

            # Add data to tbl2
            tbl2.loc[len(tbl2.index)] = [col1,col2,col3]
```

Final results as below:

[image]

Comment: refer to pandas.melt, which does the same think with one line of code